# how to display map in angular2 with result

Tags: angular

I am looking for solution to display map in angular2. Along with map I want to highlight location or area based on some data.

For example: 
1. display voting result on map by highlighting area's in different color.
2. point out all restaurants in a area.

Looking for solution which can help to implement any such functionality in angular2 application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For selecting different restaurants, I would suggest using Angular Google Maps (https://angular-maps.com/) but for highlighting regions, I would suggest using something like Highmaps (https://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo). Both have a learning curve but once you start playing with them they become easy to use.

- For AGM, it is a very powerful google maps wrapper, but there is no easy way to highlight something on the maps. Only display points and draw circles.
- For HighMaps, it is very power for displaying organized data, but it's less of a 'directional' map, and more of an 'analytical' map